# how to set Session time out in django 1.11

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to set session time_out for admin in my django==1.11 but it did not work with any of the following:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE= True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 10
SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 10
AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you note this ?

> Note
>
> Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting and prevent sessions from expiring on browser close. Please be aware of this while testing Django applications which have the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting enabled.

Comment: But in case user is inactive then what i can do for log-out automatically after certain time

Comment: like 'SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT'

Comment: Did you add   'app_name.middleware.AutoLogout', to  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES ??
And did you remember that
AUTO_LOGOUT_DELAY in minutes
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE in seconds ?

Comment: i set add 'my_app.middleware.AutoLogout' in MIDDLEWARE but it will show error:   ** in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments**